# If function for annotating from pandas

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I'm scatter plotting values from pandas dataframe. I would like to annotate points only if the value is greater than 100. I have no idea how to go about it.

Here's the code I'm working with (it's terrible but I'm very new to this):

```
female_data = r'/home/jg/Desktop/hurricanedata_f.csv'
female_df = read_csv(female_data)

male_data = r'/home/jg/Desktop/hurricanedata_m.csv'
male_df = read_csv(male_data)

x = female_df['Year']
y = female_df['alldeaths']
z = female_df['Name']
y_mean = [np.mean(y) for i in x]
a = male_df['Year']
b = male_df['alldeaths']
b_mean = [np.mean(b) for i in b]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)


ax.annotate('Agnes', xy=(1972,117))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.scatter(x,y, label = 'female', color = 'r')
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax2.scatter(a,b, label = 'male')
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax3.plot(x, y_mean, linestyle='--', color = 'r')
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax4.plot(a, b_mean, linestyle='--', color = 'blue')

plt.title('Hurricanes')
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Deaths')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.ylim([-5,300])
plt.xlim([1948,2020])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over all your data points and check if each is greater than 100. Then give those points an annotation.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import string

# Fake data
x = np.arange(10)
y = 10*np.random.rand(10) + 95
names = string.lowercase[:10] # first 10 lowercase letters

# Plot data
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.scatter(x,y)

# Annonate points with y values greater than 100 
for xi, yi, iname in zip(x,y,names): # Loop over x and y values
    if yi > 100: # Check if y is greater than 100
        ax.annotate(iname, (xi, yi),size = 30) # Add an annoatation. 

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Molly, that worked well for the most part. I can get the code to annotate with the respective y-value but not the but not with the respective name (a third df column). If I do ax.annotate(z[i], (xi, yi)) it assigns the the same name to each point (a point that's == 20 rather than >100 for some reason). I've been reading as much documentation as I can find but still haven't figured it out.

Comment: I changed my example to include different labels for each point. Hopefully that will help.